# How to change the array structure of associative array in Php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I want to change my array from, how can i make this kind of a change.

`Array (
   [0] => 53720 
   [1] => Array(
            ['Build Quality'] => 1=>10,
                                  2=>9,
                                  3=>7 
            ['Versatality'] => 1=>9,
                               2=>8,
                               3=>7 
            ['value'] => 1=>8,
                         2=>6,
                         3=>5
          )
);`

to:

`Array (
   53720 =>['Build Quality' => [1=>10,
                                2=>9,
                                3=>7],
            'Versatality' =>  [1=>9,
                               2=>8,
                               3=>7], 
            'value' => [1=>8,
                        2=>6,
                        3=>5]
           ]
);`

```
function get_array(){

  $factor = array([0] => 'Build Quality' [1] => 'Versatality' [2] => 'Value');  
  $rank = array([0] => 1=>10,2=>9,3=>7 [1] => 1=>9,2=>8,3=>7 [2] => 1=>8,2=>6,3=>5);  
  $assoc_array = array_combine($factor, $rank);
  $post_id = get_current_post_id(); //gives 53720   
  $result = array();
  array_push($result, $post_id, $assoc_array);  
  print_r($result);  
  return $result[$post_id];

/* output: Array ([0] => 53720 [1] => Array (['Build Quality'] => 1=>10,2=>9,3=>7 ['Versatality'] => 1=>9,2=>8,3=>7 ['Value'] => 1=>8,2=>6,3=>5)) */ 
}
```

Comment: Can you format input and output properly, please?

Answer (score 5):

You can add elements to an associative array directly:

```
$result = [];
$result[$post_id] = $assoc_array;
```

You can also initiate one with keys and values directly:

```
$result = [
    $post_id => $assoc_array
];
```

Also keep in mind that not any variable can be used as a key, as stated in the  [PHP documentation for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type.